How to retrieve contacts from a Random Split control group in Salesforce Marketing Cloud after 3 months?
I have a Journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud that has been running for 3 months. In this Journey:

I used a Random Split to divide contacts into 90% (who received an email) and 10% (control group – no email).
The Entry Source is a segment from Data Cloud with incremental updates.
Exit Criteria are defined as SubscriberKey IS NULL, so contacts that no longer qualify are removed.

Now, I need to retrieve the list of contacts that were in the 10% control group. Unfortunately:

The _JourneyActivity data view does not show branch-level (Random Split) activity.
The _Sent data view only shows the 90% that received the email.
API Interaction data is limited to 30 days, but this Journey has been running for 3 months.

Is there any other way in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to retrieve the contacts who were part of the 10% control group after 3 months? Or to see which contacts entered the journey or was in a specific wait activity or random split path?
I know it's possible with API but only for the data from last 30 days.

Salesforce is your best bet. Reach out to support and see if they can give you this data from backend

This isn't going to help for this journey that has already run, but if you set one up that's similar in future, I'd recommend adding an Update Contact activity to your control group path. You can then use this to log those who travel through this path to a data extension.

30 days is the limit even for support
